# Exercise and physical activity questionnaire

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, experimental-psychology, survey, exercise

I'm wondering if there exists a validated questionnaire designed to assess the duration/intensity/type of physical activity someone has taken part in over the past 1-3 days?

I've seen many questionnaires (e.g. IPAQ, link to full questionnaire [here](http://www.sdp.univ.fvg.it/sites/default/files/IPAQ_English_self-admin_long.pdf)) where the target time scale is 1 week, but I'm looking for something that captures exercise amount on a much shorter/recent time scale

Ideally it would also be short and quick to administer (for reference, I would consider both versions of the IPAQ too long)

I ask because I'm interested in people's recent levels of exercise and I've tried administering a short questionnaire where I ask things like "how many minutes of aerobic exercise did you do yesterday?" but when I looked at the the data it turns out that >70% of people report 0, so I end up with a zero-inflated variable.

This could be due to a poorly worded question, poor response format, or any number of reasons. Ideally, I would conduct a full survey design study and use factor analysis to create/validate a short form questionnaire, but at this point it might be easier to just use one that currently exists, if there is one

Does anything like this already exist?

**References**

1. Craig, C. L., Marshall, A. L., Sandstrom, M., Bauman, A. E., Booth, M. L., Ainsworth, B. E., … Oja, P. (2003). International Physical Activity Questionnaire: 12-Country Reliability and Validity. Medicine & Science in Sports & Exercise, 35(8), 1381–1395. https://doi.org/10.1249/01.MSS.0000078924.61453.FB

Comment: Interesting question. Could you perhaps provide an APA reference to the IPAQ, so other can more easily find the source?

Comment: Fair point. Added some additional information

Comment: Seems your could easily modify the source to include just 1-3 days? Normally I wouldn't recommend it, but it would certainly be a quick fix to your problem (and would seem to me to have minimal validity issues in this case, depending on your modifications).

Comment: Also, would it not be expected that your outcome is a zero inflated variable? That would align with my view on exercise prevalence (though again, it depends on your population).